# Two random numbers from $\{1,\,\cdots,\,\,n\}$. Prove probability of $x_{1} + x_{2} = n$ is $\frac{n-1}{n^2}$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

You are given two *random* natural numbers $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ from the interval $[1, n]$

Assume $n > 1$ and $x_{1}, x_{2} \sim U\{1,...,n \}$ are i.i.d.

The probability that

$$x_{1} + x_{2} = n$$ is

$$P(n) = \frac{n-1}{n^2}$$

How do I prove that?

---

For $n = 2$ possible results are:

$$S_{n=2} = \{ \{1,1\}, \{2,1 \}, \{1,2\}, \{2, 2\} \}$$

so in total $2^2 = n^2$ results. Only $\{1, 1\}$ satisfies $x_{1} + x_{2} = n$.

Therefore $p(2) = \frac{2-1}{2^2} = \frac{1}{4}$ which seems correct.

---

For $n = 3$ possible results are:

$$S_{n=3} = \{ \{1,1 \}, \{1,2 \},\{ 1,3\}, \{2,1 \}, \{2,2 \}, \{2,3 \}, \{3,1 \},  \{3,2\}, \{3,3\} \}$$

so in total $3^2 = n^2$ results. Only $\{ 1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$ satisfy $x_{1} + x_{2} = n$.

Therefore $p(3) = \frac{3-1}{3^2} = \frac{2}{9}$ which seems right.

---

Can someone prove for any $n > 1$?

Comment: Notice that any value of $x_1$ between $1$ and $n-1$ gives one value of $x_2$.

Comment: $x_1$ can be picked from $\{1,2,3, \ldots, n-1\}$ but then $x_2$'s fate is sealed.

Comment: "randomly given two natural numbers" --> "given two random natural numbers"

Comment: That's how I derived the probability function. I am unsure how would the formal proof look like, though.

Comment: *True randomness* is not the usual of jargon used in probability. What you mean to say is that $x_1, x_2 \sim U\{1,\ldots,n\}$ are i.i.d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "true randomness" you mean that $x_1,x_2\sim U\{1,\ldots,n\}$ are i.i.d., then
\begin{multline*}
\mathbb{P}(x_{1}+x_{2}=n)=\mathbb{P}(x_{2}=n-x_{1})=\sum_{i}\mathbb{P}(x_{2}=n-x_{1}\mid x_{1}=i)\mathbb{P}(x_{1}=i)\\
=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathbb{P}(x_{2}=n-i)\mathbb{P}(x_{1}=i)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n-1}{n^{2}}.
\end{multline*}